# Anaconda/Spyder: Issues with plotting using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am using Spyder IDE that comes with Anaconda and have the following issues:

1. At the end of the plotting commands, I issue plt.grid() and this does not show a grid. Even when I issue plt.show() it doesn't work. If I issue plt.grid() a couple of times at the console/command line (ipython console), I get it to work.
2. Whenever the plotting command works and I have an interactive plot window, the plot window always shows up as "not responding" initially and then I see the figures. This is more of an annoyance as I can always get the plot at the end.

Any suggestions to fix these issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that `plt.grid()` toggled between on and off. To turn the grid on independently of it's previous state use `plt.grid(True)`.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) If you're setting the matplotlib backed you use in your script, then I think you need to disable our integration in `Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Activate support` for things to work as expected.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That was it for the grid. Thanks. Carlos Cordoba: Thanks for your response. My settings are as you mentioned from the start.